# Where to find TemplateId while creating custom directory role MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-rbac, azure-identity

I want to create custom directory role with specific permissions like:

```bash
microsoft.directory/users/create
microsoft.directory/users/delete
microsoft.directory/groups/create
microsoft.directory/groups/delete
microsoft.directory/applications/create
microsoft.directory/applications/delete
microsoft.directory/serviceprincipals/create
microsoft.directory/serviceprincipals/delete
```

I found how to automate this from MS graph:

POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions

Body

```
{
   "description": "Can manage basic aspects of application registrations.",
   "displayName": "Application Support Administrator",
   "isEnabled": true,
   "templateId": "<GUID>",
   "rolePermissions": [
       {
           "allowedResourceActions": [
microsoft.directory/users/create
microsoft.directory/users/delete microsoft.directory/groups/create
microsoft.directory/groups/delete
microsoft.directory/applications/create
microsoft.directory/applications/delete
microsoft.directory/serviceprincipals/create
microsoft.directory/serviceprincipals/delete
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

What is template Id and how to get the value of this?

TIA

Comment: templateId String Custom template identifier that can be set when isBuiltIn is false but is read-only when isBuiltIn is true. This identifier is typically used if one needs an identifier to be the same across different directories.

From this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/unifiedroledefinition?view=graph-rest-1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Note** that, `"templateId": "<GUID>"` is an optional parameter and you can include it while creating multiple custom directory roles with common parameters.

To get the value of **"templateId"**, you can create one **GUID** using this PowerShell command:    **`(New-Guid).Guid`**

[image]

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment via [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) and got below results:***

I ran the **same query** as you and created **custom directory role** from MS Graph like below:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleDefinitions

{
"description": "Can manage basic aspects of application registrations.",
"displayName": "Application Support Administrator",
"isEnabled": true,
"templateId": "38837bf2-39d8-4c14-89f3-3e9c5e6c9b23", //GUID created from PowerShell
"rolePermissions": [
    {
        "allowedResourceActions": [
            "microsoft.directory/users/create",
            "microsoft.directory/users/delete",
            "microsoft.directory/groups/create",
            "microsoft.directory/groups/delete",
            "microsoft.directory/applications/create",
            "microsoft.directory/applications/delete",
            "microsoft.directory/serviceprincipals/create",
            "microsoft.directory/serviceprincipals/delete"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, I am able to find the new **custom directory role** like below:

[image]

To assign this role to **user** via Graph API, you can make use of below query:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments
{
    "principalId":"<GUID OF USER>",
    "roleDefinitionId":"<GUID OF ROLE DEFINITION>",
    "directoryScopeId":"/<GUID OF APPLICATION REGISTRATION(ObjectID)>"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, role assigned to **user** successfully like below:

[image]